# image not appearing in popmenu in android?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button  
    android:id="@+id/button1"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"  
    android:text="Show Popup" />
```

//

/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

          button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu




            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());  
            //popup.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_quit_icon);

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener 

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  

             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) { 

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method  
         } 


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

//this is main activity

popup working properly but  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" not working no image/icon appearing in popmenu, Please tell me how can i set icon in popmenu in android .
i am new in android.

Comment: set showAsAction="ifRoom".

Comment: sir, set showAsAction="ifRoom" is showing image on right on the title not in popupmenu

Comment: Please check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836454/1552622

Answer (score 1):

Change line:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

or

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: sir its give icon  on titlebar  but not in popupmenu, my popupmenu working on button's click

Comment: then you have to make another xml file for that popupmenu and set above line for that.

Comment: sir , i am making that file in /res/menu/main.xml but it is also not working. i want to know that there is any issue with popmenu like context menu or etc...

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
        

</menu> //main.xml

Comment: i am asking code for showing popupmenu..and dont post here.. edit it in your question please.

Comment: sir , i gave my problem above in my question

Comment: is it possible to add the layout file in popup menu. if possible how ???....but sir in main.xml file a property is android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" why it is not working.....

Comment: item1 ,item2,item3 and their images /icon